# I have a IDictionaryEnumerator set as ResourceReader.GetEnumerator, How do i get a list of all the resources?

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
var assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var fs = assem.GetManifestResourceStream("res.resources");
var rr = new ResourceReader(fs);`
IDictionaryEnumerator dict = rr.GetEnumerator();
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

You could use LINQ to convert the data provided by your `ResourceReader` to the dictionary which might be easier to work with:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

var assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var fs = assem.GetManifestResourceStream("res.resources");
var rr = new ResourceReader(fs);

Dictionary<string, object> data = rr
                .OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
                .Select(i => new { Key = i.Key.ToString(), value = i.Value })
                .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.value);

// Getting all resource names
IEnumerable<string> names = data.Keys;

// Getting all values
IEnumerable<object> values = data.Values;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcereader.aspx):

```
var assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var fs = assem.GetManifestResourceStream("res.resources");
var rr = new ResourceReader(fs);`
IDictionaryEnumerator dict = rr.GetEnumerator();    
while (dict.MoveNext())
   Console.WriteLine("   {0}: '{1}' (Type {2})", 
                     dict.Key, dict.Value, dict.Value.GetType().Name);
rr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of all the resources in an assembly use the following

```
var assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); 
var resources = assem.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

Comment: Then how would i get the Values of the resources?